# How to modify .htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess

When I link to a file in a directory, I want to open that file as a param in a php program.

For example, I have a directory `temp`, and files `aa.txt`, `bb.txt`, and `test.php`. When I link to `aa.txt` it should be handled like `test.php?f=aa.txt`.

What do I change in the .htaccess file?

the code in the test.php

```
<?php
$f=$_GET['f'];
if(@file_exists($f)){
    $inhoud = file_get_contents($f);
}else{
    $inhoud = "Not found\n";
}
print "hallo <hr>".$inhoud;

?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to use [mod_rewrite](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html), and define rules like the following within a .htaccess file in the directory you want it to apply to:

```
# Enable mod_rewrite
RewriteEngine on

# If the request is an actual file and not test.php...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !test.php$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f

# ... then rewrite the URL to pass the filename as a parameter to test.php
RewriteRule /(.*)$ test.php?f=$1 [QSA]
```

Comment: i tested and it shows the original content of the file (a.txt ) my script just puts hello in front of the result

Comment: i added the source of test.php

Comment: Looks like it's doing exactly what you told it to do. `file_get_contents` gets the content of a file and then you're echoing it. If you want to do something else with the file and can't figure out how to do so, you should create another question.

Comment: it shows the original content of the aa.txt and if i remove the file aa.txt it doesnt show "not found" what am i doing wrong? (hallo doesnt show either ( tested it on two servers )

Comment: If the file doesn't exist, the second `RewriteCond` will fail (because it's checking if the file exists). If you want your script to handle a non-existant file, remove the second `RewriteCond`.

Comment: well still not working. The .htaccess wont execute test.php it just shows the original content of aa.txt

Comment: found the solution and its working now
solution from vandersluis ( dutch name? ) was very helpful
the link to test.php must contain full url like var/www/domain/www/test.php

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !test.php #Do not rewrite the test.php file
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} -f        #Requested filename exists
RewriteRule (.*) test.php?f=$1 [QSA,L]
```